# How to send excel (.xlsx) file with nodemailer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, nodes, nodemailer

I've tried numerous ways to do it using the github README.md guide, but every time I receive an email, it contains 0 bytes. What am I doing wrong?

Basic setup:

```
const smtpTransport = mailer.createTransport({
    service: "Gmail",
    auth: {
        user: gmailEmail,
        pass: gmailPass
    }
});
let wef = fs.readFileSync("./" + fileName);
let mailOptions = {
    to: ['myemail@gmail.com'],
    subject: 'Subject line'
    attachments: [{
        contents: new Buffer(wef)
    }]
};
smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response) {
    smtpTransport.close();
    cb(error || null);
});
```

I've tried tons of combinations with changing the mailOptions by adding different attachment types, different contents, different contentTypes, and no matter what I do, I always get a file with 0 bytes. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Nodemailer is crap, don't use it. Ended up using 'gmail-send', works perfectly.